# Passing down a hidden ability in Pokemon Black 2

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

I have a female Pinsir with the hidden ability Moxie. If I were to breed it with a male Heracross, is there a chance I could hatch a Moxie Heracross or would all the offsprings be Moxie Pinsir?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! If you found the answer useful, please accept it by pressing the green "tick" symbol.

Answer (score 2):

A female Pinsir will only make eggs containing more Pinsir, never Heracross. Of those Pinsir, 80% will have their hidden Ability, while the remaining 20% will have a random, non-hidden Ability.

Comment: Sorry, still confused why a Heracross can't be hatched. They are in the same egg group and share a hidden ability. Or is that how to game mechanic work in this game? Thanks for answering by the way

Comment: Eggs will always contain the mother's species, except rare cases like Nidoran♂ and Nidoran♀ which are counted as the same species. An egg from a Nidoran♀ can hatch into either a Nidoran♂ or a Nidoran♀.

Comment: Ah... my only solution is to search for a HA Heracross in Lostlorn Forest then. Thank you!